# UIBarButtonItem font in LaunchScreen storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, launch-screen

I'm using custom fonts inside my iOS app.
Obviously, I want to implement nice GUI correlated with iOS UI Apple Guidelines.
I want to use Launch Screen Storyboard with my UI buttons. But I'm using my custom fonts. And I have not found where I can change font `UIBarButtonItem` in the preferences inside storyboard.
So, is it possible to implement custom font for `UIBarButtonItem` ?

Comment: You can probably do it using `UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView)`, but you have to create your `customView` yourself (it can be `UIButton` actually).

Comment: custom views are not allowed for LaunchScreen. They yeild compiler fault.

Comment: you also can use `setTitleTextAttributes:forState` method of `UIBarItem` but, still, you can't do that in `LaunchScreen`. I'm quite sure that you must implement your own Launch Screen (presenting a `UIViewController` for a few seconds manually) to achieve what you want

Comment: Then I would suggest, although it is ugly, to save Title (I think that is the thing you're trying to present with custom font) as the Image. And present it as the image on top of the screen.